# mhchem reaction arrows seem to break when using a command in the \ce environment

Tags: macros, mhchem

I've tried making the command

```
\newcommand{\aq}{_{(aq)}}
```

to make the subscript to show that an ion is aqueous, but when used in the `\ce` command it breaks the reaction arrows

```
\ce{2Cu(OH2)^{2+}_{6} + 4I^{-}\aq  <=> 2CuI v +I2 v +12H2O}
```

Comment: BTW: IUPAC recommends to typeset “the states of aggregation of chemical species [...] appended to the formula in parentheses and [...] printed in Roman (upright) type without a full stop (period).” This means: not as a subscript.

Answer (score 2):

`mhchem`'s arrows *need* to be preceded with a space. Since a command “eats” spaces after it there is *no* space before the arrow here: `\ce{\cs <=>}`. So that's why you need to add an empty group `{}` (`\ce{\cs{} <=>}`) or enclose the command with braces (`\ce{{\cs} <=>}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

without space: \ce{A<=>} \\
with space: \ce{A <=>}

\def\B{B}\bigskip
without space: \ce{\B <=>} \\
with space: \ce{\B{} <=>} \\
with space: \ce{{\B} <=>}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed if you use `{}` immediately following `\aq`:

```
\ce{2Cu(OH2)^{2+}_{6} + 4I^{-}\aq{} <=> 2CuI v +I2 v +12H2O}
```

[image: mhchem and newcommand]